# Accessing Amazon EFS from CommandLine and creating folder inside it

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, filesystems, cloud, amazon-efs

If we have EFS mounted on any instance, then we can access the instance and create a folder in its mount path, but I have EFS all alone and it is not mounted on any of the instance.
How can I now create a folder in the EFS via command line?. Is there any other way that I can access the EFS and create a folder?

Comment: How did it go with the issue? Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't create folders and files on EFS without mounting it. You simply **have to mount** it to some instance, lambda or ecs container to be able to access or create files on the EFS filesystem.